# What does postcompose mean when talking about lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

When reading various papers about the lambda calculus, ISWIM and a number of other things, I have heard the word "postcompose" come up a lot (e.g. in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_operator). However, after a lot of research, I could not find anything (except one definition that mathematical and unrelated to what I was looking for). So, what does "postcompose" mean?

Comment: Do you have any example or reference?

Comment: I added one talking about the J Operator

Comment: from that article's open is seems `g = J f = k . f` such that `g x = k (f x)` (where `k` is the calling function's continuation, I guess that function where the `J f` call appears).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *postcompose* is not specific to the lambda calculus. It really just means *compose* in the context of two functions, operators, functors or whatever objects on which composition is defined. The *post* prefix is used to disambiguate the order of composition, so *post*composing *f* with *g* is *g* ∘ *f* = *g(f(x))*.

In the context of lambda calculus, you have e.g. function application which is composable.